# Google Script Move selection to specific cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to move the cursor (select cell) when the user clicks on the Sheet.
I've tried so many options and none of them work. The cursor just stays where I click, instead of moving to the specified cell.
Note: I change the background color of the clicked cell just to make sure the selection trigger is working.

```
  function onSelectionChange(e) {
  
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

 
  range.setBackground("blue");

  sheet.setCurrentCell("a1").activate();
 
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

***The `setCurrentCell` method is never executed because you are using the wrong parameter for it.***

According to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setcurrentcellcell), `setCurrentCell` expects an object of type 'Range`, *however, you are passing a string to it.*

In order to fix this, you should update your function to this:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  range.setBackground("blue");
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
  sheet.setCurrentCell(cell);
}
```

Also, since you are using the `onSelectionChange` trigger, for best practices, it is recommended you make use of the `e` event object, hence the modifications above.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Spreadsheet Class - setCurrentCell(cell)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setcurrentcellcell);
- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

Answer (score 0):

```
function onOpen() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
   var columnToFocus = 1; /* Change this to the column number you want to focus on (A=1, B=2, etc.) */
   /* Get the last row with data in the specified column*/
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
   while (lastRow > 0 && sheet.getRange(lastRow, columnToFocus).getValue() === "") {
      lastRow--;
   }
   /*Set focus on the next empty cell in the specified column*/
   var nextEmptyRow = lastRow + 1;
   var cell = sheet.getRange(nextEmptyRow, columnToFocus);
   sheet.setActiveRange(cell);
}
```